Execute DDL command on JDBC server using Apache Beam
I have a usecase wherein a remote SQL server has to be truncated and then data has to be loaded using Google Dataflow. Using WriteToJDBC module I am able to insert records in the sql server, but how can I perform DDL operations?
 with TestPipeline() as p:
      _ = (
          p
          | beam.Create([ExampleRow(1, 'abc')])
              .with_output_types(ExampleRow)
          | 'Write to jdbc' >> WriteToJdbc(
              table_name='jdbc_external_test_write'
              driver_class_name='com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver',
              jdbc_url='jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/example',
              username='postgres',
              password='postgres',
          ))

